# VBA excel function

Tags: excel, vba

I need to make an Excel macro that takes triangle side length and makes sure it exists and it if does it needs to output what type of triangle it is.

Whenever I type values `a = 2`, `b = 2` and `c = 2`, it should be an equilateral triangle but it outputs it as an a isosceles triangle.

Any help appreciated!

```
Public Function triangle(a, b, c) As String
Select Case True
Case a + b <= c Or a + c <= b Or c + b <= a
triangle = "Doesnt exist"
Case a = b Or c = b Or a = c
triangle = "Isosceles"
Case (a + b) ^ 2 = c ^ 2 Or (b + c) ^ 2 = b ^ 2 Or (c + a) ^ 2 = a ^ 2
triangle = "right triangle"
Case a = b = c
triangle = "Equilateral"
Case Else
triangle = "Regular triangle"

End Select

MsgBox triangle

End Function
```

Comment: It meets the criteria for Isosceles before it gets to equilateral.

Comment: Also i don't believe a = b = c will work in VBA, you need ```and``` statements.

Comment: @Warcupine so.. you're posting an answer or I submit my draft? ;-)

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Have at it, yours will be better explained than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Case` blocks evaluate top-to-bottom, and whichever branch first matches the condition (i.e. whichever is the first to be `True`) will be the winning condition.

Thus, you should evaluate the most constrained rules first, and the less constrained ones last - meaning you need to check for an equilateral triangle before you check for an isosceles one, since an equilateral triangle is also isosceles, [as Warcupine already noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57858819/vba-excel-function/57858965#comment102143889_57858819).

But there's a problem with the equilateral condition:

```
Case a = b = c
```

VBA will evaluate `a = b` as a `Boolean` expression, and then take the result of that and compare it to `c` - so if `c` is any non-zero value, `a = b = c` will be `True` regardless of the value of `c` (assuming non-zero) if both `a` and `b` are equal.

If the function is intended to be used as a UDF, consider avoiding `MsgBox` calls, and returning a `Variant` so that you can yield an actual Excel cell error value given invalid inputs - note that what you call a "regular triangle" probably falls under the definition of a [scalene triangle](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ScaleneTriangle.html):

```
Public Function TriangleType(ByVal a As Double, ByVal b As Double, ByVal c As Double) As Variant
    If a <= 0 Or b <= 0 Or c <= 0 Then
        TriangleType = CVErr(xlErrValue)
        Exit Function
    End If

    Select Case True
        Case a + b <= c Or a + c <= b Or c + b <= a
            TriangleType = CVErr(xlErrValue)

        Case a = b And b = c And c = a
            TriangleType = "Equilateral"
        Case a = b Or c = b Or a = c
            TriangleType = "Isosceles"
        'Case (a + b) ^ 2 = c ^ 2 Or (b + c) ^ 2 = b ^ 2 Or (c + a) ^ 2 = a ^ 2
        Case a ^ 2 + b ^ 2 = c ^ 2 Or b ^ 2 + c ^ 2 = a ^ 2 Or c ^ 2 + a ^ 2 = b ^ 2
            TriangleType = "Right Triangle"

        Case Else
            TriangleType = "Scalene Triangle"
    End Select

End Function
```

Comment: That ```a=b=c``` explanation was what I couldn't explain, just knew it wasn't valid, +1 for knowledge.

Comment: FYI, there's also a problem with the OP's Right Triangle  condition

Comment: @Mathieu not quite.  Should be `a^2 +b^2 =c^2` etc

Comment: @chrisneilsen lol, I math hates me (*actually* fixed now) - thanks!

Comment: Thinking about this some more,  this shows a weakness in the OPs classification logic: a triangle can be both Isosceles and Right. Should the function report both?  And the floating point precision issue definitely needs to be addressed.   As is, some of these tests will fail on all but a few special cases

Comment: @chrisneilsen true - perhaps a better return type would be some `TriangleType` enum with power-of-2 values, such that e.g. an equilateral triangle would have both `TriangleType.Equilateral` and `TriangleType.Isosceles` flags on.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to think about numerical considerations! At what point of accuracy you want to consider a triangle a "right triangle"?

3 + 4 + 5 => right triangle

3 + 4 + 5,000001 => regular (scalene) triangle (right now!!)

```
Option Explicit

Public Function triangle(a, b, c) As String

If a + b <= c Or a + c <= b Or c + b <= a Then
    triangle = "Doesnt exist"
ElseIf a = b And a = c And b = c Then
    triangle = "equilateral"
ElseIf a = b Or c = b Or a = c Then
    triangle = "isosceles"
ElseIf (a ^ 2 + b ^ 2) = c ^ 2 Or (b ^ 2 + c ^ 2) = b ^ 2 Or (c ^ 2 + a ^ 2) = a ^ 2 Then
    triangle = "right triangle"
Else
    triangle = "regular (scalene) triangle"
End If

Debug.Print a, b, c, " --> ", triangle

End Function
```

Comment: Good point. This is true for anything involving float-point values!